# jQuery dropdown menu mouseleave problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/borayeris/sb9Ju/4/

Here is my script. How can I stop fading out if mouse is back on menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a call to [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) on the fadeIn:

```
$(function(){
    var piFade;
    $('#menu > li').hover(
      function(){
        $('#menu > li:hover > div').stop(true,true).fadeIn('slow');
      },
      function(){
        $('#menu > li > div').fadeOut('slow');
      }
    );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sb9Ju/13/

And here is a version with the delay included.  I'm not a huge fan but it's not too bad with the call to stop in there.

http://jsfiddle.net/sb9Ju/15/

Comment: First of all thank you. I read `stop` before sending this question here. But could not understand how to use it. I even try that stupid way. http://jsfiddle.net/borayeris/Em2Kd/1/ Can you teach me how `stop` behaves in your example?

Comment: It just stops the current animation.  The idea is when you `mouseIn` it will stop the `mouseOut` animation if it is taking place.  The two parameters are for "clearQueue" and "jumpToEnd".  The most important one for you is the clearQueue, which will stop animations from lining up and getting executed one after the other.  If you didn't have that and you moused over/out five times it would do the animation 5 times.

Comment: But here I don't understand why we use `stop` in fadeIn. My brain says I must use it in fadeOut. I know I am wrong but why? What's the logic of it?

Answer (score 0):

You set too long a delay. It still runs the original hover function.
You remove it, it waits 2.5 second, then you back on it and it still removes menu from the first time you've hovered.
I really don't see a reason to use delay there.

Comment: Because I want menu to stay 2-3 seconds even mouse is out.